# Kernel panic - unable to mount root fs on unknown block (0,0)

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

Here is boot-repair info:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FSdKqJdF8n/

I tried countless solutions during last 2 weeks but nothing helps :(

May be, there is some hard-reset way to solve the problem?
I tried to format disk, but that doesn't help also.

Comment: Well, the first thing to do would be to boot up a repair-CD (e.g. "Knoppix") and use that environment to see what is the *actual* situation on this disk:  is it formatted, if so in what way.  Then make sure exactly where and how it's attached to your system.  The "grub configuration" (in `/boot`) will among other things specify where the root filesystem must live and what drivers (if any) are needed to use it.  Look very carefully at messages *immediately preceding* the kernel-panic message.

Comment: First, are you able to see the GRUB menu, and if so, can you boot to an earlier kernel? How did you try and format the disk? Second, boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open `terminal` and type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2`. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema  
`$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2  

fsck from util-linux 2.31.1  
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)  
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes  
    Pass 2: Checking directory structure  
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity  
Pass 4: Checking reference counts  
Pass 5: Checking group summary information  
/dev/sda2: 143168/7782400 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 2271862/31127296 blocks`

Comment: I can see GRUB menu, but it doesn't give me to choose between many kernels, there is only one kernel available there.

Comment: @schw90 You should always keep at least one old kernel around for just this kind of problem. If you can get to Recovery Mode from the GRUB menu, I can probably give you instructions for how to fix your problem. Report back.